# System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors

Tags: exception, triggers, salesforce, apex

The below code snippet is in Opportunity afterUpdate trigger. I am trying to update the accounts of those affected opportunities and after getting DMLException, the code enters catch block and I get

> 'System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors' at row  a.Id.addError(de.getMessage());

Please let me know what is wrong with the line a.Id.addError(de.getMessage());

```
if (acctLst.size() > 0) {
   try{
       update acctLst;
   } catch(Exception de) {
       for (Account a : acctLst) {
           a.Id.addError(de.getMessage());
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add error to a **sObject field** `a.Id` but error should be added to the sObject like that

```
a.addError(de.getMessage());
```